# Why am I having trouble installing npm modules?

Tags: node.js, terminal, npm, react-native

I want to install the react-native-cli module but haven't been able to do so, or with any other module.

I'm trying the following:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

What happens is that the terminal processes the instruction, but then yields an error. I've used node in windows for a few days now and I have been able to install successfully, but maybe because I am a Mac newbie something is going wrong.

I've wondered if node is actually installed. In the terminal if I write "node" the cursor changes from $ to >, which I guess it's a good sign. I can even do things such as:

```
node >console.log('Hello World!');
```

and get it working perfectly. However if I do:

```
node >--version
```

it doesn't work.

So is node properly installed? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the error :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo npm install -g react-native-cli
```

To check the version use

```
node --version
```

Thanks

Comment: I am using a a computer which isn't mine and wouldn't like screwing anything up. What does the sudo command do? How do I know I am using it properly?

Comment: `Sudo` command will not break anything, it will get you the admin privileges to get the package installed smoothly on your system.

Comment: @AndyRay, the official OS X installer on Node's site sets things up in a way that requires sudo to globally install some packages. Agree with the sentiment of your comment though - it's a lot better to install Node/io.js through brew or nvm.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that you do not have write permission to the bin directory npm is trying to use for global installation. Easiest solution is to use `sudo`:

```
sudo npm install -g react-native-cli
```

However, many would argue that the more correct solution is to change the setup so that you have write privileges to the directory without using `sudo` (which will prompt you for your password and then run with elevated permissions--I'm assuming you have administrative privileges on your Mac).

To check the version of node, do not include the `>`. It's just `node --version`.

To find out what binary you are executing when you type `node`, you can run `type -a node` or `which node`.

Comment: It's actually not my Mac, so the only thing I want to do is not break anything!

Answer (score 0):

Considering `console.log('Hello World!');` works there should not be any problem with node installation.

To check version from command line just execute

```
C:\Users\athakur>node --version
v0.10.31
```

From nodejs console do

```
> console.log(process.versions);
{ http_parser: '1.0',
  node: '0.10.31',
  v8: '3.14.5.9',
  ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
  uv: '0.10.28',
  zlib: '1.2.3',
  modules: '11',
  openssl: '1.0.1i' }
```